# Flask App Builder throws KeyError on arrays

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table with an attribute of type array of string:

```
create table mytable(
        suffix VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,
        label VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        sourceuris VARCHAR(200)[],
);
```

It is defined in `models.py` as:

```
class mytable(Model):
    suffix = Column(String(200), primary_key=True)
    label =  Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    sourceuris = Column(ARRAY(String(200)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label
```

Now I want to define a view on it using Flask AppBuilder in `views.py`:

```
class mytable(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(mytable)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    label_columns = {'label':'Name'}
    list_columns = ['suffix', 'label', 'sourceuris']
```

It compiles but when I open the view in the web application at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/mytableviewview/list/`, then I get a `KeyError: 'sourceuris':

```
2020-08-26 12:50:42,329:WARNING:flask_appbuilder.models.filters:Filter type not supported for column: sourceuris
2020-08-26 12:50:42,329:WARNING:flask_appbuilder.models.filters:Filter type not supported for column: sourceuris
2020-08-26 12:50:42,332:WARNING:flask_appbuilder.models.filters:Filter type not supported for column: sourceuris
2020-08-26 12:50:42,394:ERROR:app:Exception on /mytableview/list/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 109, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/views.py", line 552, in list
    return self.render_template(
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 280, in render_template
    return render_template(
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/list.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% import 'appbuilder/general/lib.html' as lib %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends base_template %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/app/templates/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'appbuilder/baselayout.html' %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/baselayout.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% import 'appbuilder/baselib.html' as baselib %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/init.html", line 46, in top-level template code
    {% block body %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/baselayout.html", line 19, in block "body"
    {% block content %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/list.html", line 7, in block "content"
    {% block list_search scoped %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/list.html", line 8, in block "list_search"
    {% call lib.accordion_tag("accordion1",_("Search"), False) %}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 679, in _invoke
    rv = self._func(*arguments)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/lib.html", line 291, in template
    {{ caller() }}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 679, in _invoke
    rv = self._func(*arguments)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/model/list.html", line 9, in template
    {{ widgets.get('search')()|safe }}
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/widgets.py", line 114, in __call__
    label_columns[col] = as_unicode(self.template_args["form"][col].label.text)
  File "/home/konrad/projekte/hito/database-frontend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 64, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[name]
KeyError: 'sourceuris'
```

The error persists even when I remove 'sourceuris' from the list_columns array.

How can I get Flask AppBuilder to display arrays without errors?

Edit: I implemented the suggestion of @mehdy, however creating doesn't work and on edit I cannot change the size of the array. See the screenshots below:

### View

Viewing works fine.
[image: viewing works fine]

### Edit

Editing only works if the array size stays the same.
[image: editing only works if the array size stays the same]

### Create

Creating doesn't work because the array is initially empty and I cannot increase the size to even one element.

[image: creating doesn't work because the array is initially empty and I cannot increase the size to even one element]

Note that the array in the real case is called "synonyms", not "sourceuris" as in the minimal example.

Comment: Could you please add your model definition as well? and other related codes if there are any.

Comment: @mehdy: I added the model definition as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `search` form fields. To avoid that you can exclude `sourceuris` from `search` form fields as follow.

```py
    search_exclude_columns = ['sourceuris']
```

But since `Flask-AppBuilder` doesn't support `Array` fields, you have to add these to attributes as well to get it to work.

```py
from wtforms import FieldList, StringField

add_form_extra_fields = {'sourceuris': FieldList(StringField('Source URIs'), min_entries=1)}
edit_form_extra_fields = {'sourceuris': FieldList(StringField('Source URIs'), min_entries=1)}
```

All these three attributes have to be added to your `ModelView` class.

Comment: Do you mean the StringField and FieldList from the wtforms package? It doesn't crash anymore and successfully shows the array when viewing it, however I cannot change the amount of elements in the array when editing and I cannot add more than one element at creation.

Comment: Sure! I edited the answer as well. I checked the editing scenario in it worked fine for me. Could you please tell me more about how the editing doesn't work? And about adding new elements, I think it's out of this question's scope. Creating dynamic forms with wtforms FieldList would be starting point.

Comment: Well the editing works partially. If I have 3 elements and I change them to 3 other elements then it works. But I cannot go from 3 elements to 2 or 4. I added screenshots to my post to clarify.